# print hex-code in string

Tags: string, characters, print, escape

I hope `"*ielm*"`/`eval-print-last-sexp` print `"\x80"`, but the result is

```lisp
ELISP> "\x80"
"\200"  ; Unicode characters should be displayed normally.
```

My current settings:

```lisp
(setq print-escape-newlines t
      print-escape-control-characters nil
      ctl-arrow t
      print-escape-multibyte nil
      display-raw-bytes-as-hex t)
```